# Find highest point of 3D line with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, 3d

I need to find the highest point of a 3D line. To do so I use `ST_ZMax` to obtain the Z-coordinate of the highest point:

```
SELECT ST_ZMax(geom) FROM 3dlines;
```

How can I find the X- and Y-coordinates of this point?

Answer (score 2):

2 ways to do it

1) use st_dumppoints and order by st_z

2) create a polygon above your linestring and use st_3dclosestpoint to find your highest point.

Answer (score 0):

select the point where z = ST_ZMax(geom)